# xib is not opened in Xcode in a default MonoTouch application

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, xib, xamarin

I've just created a MonoTouch solution using MonoDevelop and after I'm trying open the xib in XCode for editing, I get the following exception (and the xib not opens):

```
System.NotSupportedException: Custom attribute type 0x43 is not supported.
at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TypeSystem.CecilLoader+BlobReader.ReadCustomAttributeFieldOrPropType () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TypeSystem.CecilLoader+BlobReader.ReadNamedArg (IType attributeType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TypeSystem.CecilLoader+CecilResolvedAttribute.DecodeBlob (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 positionalArguments, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 namedArguments) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TypeSystem.CecilLoader+CecilResolvedAttribute.DecodeBlob () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TypeSystem.CecilLoader+CecilResolvedAttribute.get_PositionalArguments () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MonoDevelop.MacDev.ObjCIntegration.NSObjectInfoService.ConvertType (MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem.ProjectContentWrapper dom, ITypeDefinition type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MonoDevelop.MacDev.ObjCIntegration.NSObjectInfoService+<GetRegisteredObjects>c__Iterator2.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MonoDevelop.MacDev.ObjCIntegration.NSObjectProjectInfo.Update () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MonoDevelop.MacDev.ObjCIntegration.NSObjectProjectInfo.Update (Boolean force) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MonoDevelop.MacDev.XcodeSyncing.XcodeProjectTracker.UpdateTypes (IProgressMonitor monitor) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

The application compiles and run fine though....

Comment: I have the same error, I just installed the MonoTouch eval. OSX 10.7.2, Xcode 4.2.1, MonoDevelop 3.0.3.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Restart XCode and MonoTouch, it should solve this problem...

Answer (score 1):

I restarted MonoDevelop and XCode, but still had the same problem. Until I find a better solution, I am doing it this way:

1. Open an existing solution in XCode.
2. Open the xib file to lauch the Interface Builder (from within XCode).
3. While in Interface Builder, go File>Open.
4. Navigate to the xib file that was created in MonoDevelop.

I can't find a way of launching the Interface Builder without opening an existing XCode solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tried restarting/reinstalling/rebooting to no avail.

I solved my issue by removing a reference to a **Portable Library** project I created in the same solution.  Portable Library claims it supports MonoTouch, but perhaps it is not meant to reference MonoTouch itself (because then it wouldn't be portable to other platforms.)  I did get some compilation warnings related to it referencing MonoTouch.

Instead, I created a new project from the **MonoTouch Library Project** project template, moved my files there, and I can again edit XIB's / Storyboards as expected in the Interface Builder from MonoDevelop.

Alternative: Instead of creating a new project and moving my files, what I actually did was  changed the <ProjectTypeGuids>...</ProjectTypeGuids> in my csproj file to match the MonoTouch Library project, as this was easier for me:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{786C830F-07A1-408B-BD7F-6EE04809D6DB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3
-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Comment: Here is the related bug Xamarin's bug database: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6071